# Tensorflow: Failed to create session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get an error when I run my code, the error is:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ...
import ...

checkpoint='/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/model/'
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/model/"

def getAllImages(folder):
    assert os.path.exists(folder)
    assert os.path.isdir(folder)
    imageList = os.listdir(folder)
    imageList = [os.path.join(folder,item) for item in imageList ]
    num=len(imageList)
    return imageList,num

def get_labei():
    img_dir, num = getAllImages(r"/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/model/file/")
    for i in range(num):
        image = Image.open(img_dir[i])
        image = image.resize([56, 56])
        image = np.array(image)
        image_array = image

        with tf.Graph().as_default():
            image = tf.cast(image_array, tf.float32)
            image_1 = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
            image_2 = tf.reshape(image_1, [1, 56, 56, 3])

            logit = color_inference.inference(image_2)
            y = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[56, 56, 3])

            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            with tf.Session() as sess:
              ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
              if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                   global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
                   saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                   print('Loading success, global_step is %s' % global_step)
                   prediction = sess.run(y)
                   max_index = np.argmax(prediction)
              else:
                   print('No checkpoint file found')

        path='/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/move_file/'+str(max_index)
        isExists = os.path.exists(path)
        if not isExists :
            os.makedirs(path)
        shutil.copyfile(img_dir[i], path)

def main(argv=None):
    get_labei()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

And here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/model/color_class_2.py", line 61, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/model/color_class_2.py", line 58, in main
    get_labei()
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/data/model/color_class_2.py", line 40, in get_labei
    with tf.Session() as sess:
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1187, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 552, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

Comment: You didn't initialize the variables of your graph. Add this line `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()` before `with tf.Session() as sess`. And add this `sess.run(init_op)` after `with tf.Session() as sess:`

Comment: Mind accepting an answer as correct? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using GPU? If yes, maybe it's just simply out of GPU Memory due to the previous process failed to be killed.

This ticket helps me identify the problem: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9549

To see your GPU status: in terminal, `nvidia-smi -l 2` to update your gpu stat every 2 seconds

This post shows you how to kill the process that currently taking all the memory of your GPU: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-kill-all-the-computer-processes-shown-in-nvidia-smi

Answer (score 12):

Happened to me when I had a separate Tensorflow session running in another terminal. Closing that terminal made it work.

Answer (score 5):

maybe out of GPU memory? Try running with

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
```

Also please provide details about what platform you are using (operating system, architecture). Also include your TensorFlow version.

Were you able to create a simple session from python console. Something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('hi,tensorflow')
sess = tf.Session()
```

Comment: I restart my computer and this problem is solved .But I don't know why...

Comment: Possibly a memory issue. Restarting will clear any locks on the memory and will clear it out.

Comment: After export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' is used, no GPU acceleration is being used now. Also, if I work on a server, how can I handle it? I can't restart a server.

Answer (score 3):

After you execute

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
```

your tensorflow may not use GPU. It may start training the model using CPU only.

You can find a better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48515395/5254777). This doesn't require any restart, and you can apply it in server.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem and this is what I did:

1. Nvidia Driver:

   $ nvidia-smi
   | NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130

Found driver 384.130

2. Updated Driver

   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

   $ sudo apt update

The above log showed nvidia 396 is being installed.

```
nvidia_396:
 Running module version sanity check.
```

Restarted machine and checked nvidia driver:

```
 $ nvidia-smi
 NVIDIA-SMI 396.54                 Driver Version: 396.54
```

Checked nvcc:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Checked Cuda:

```
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
CUDA Version 9.0.176
```

Checked Conda & Tensroflow

```
$ conda list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                1.10.0          gpu_py36hcebf108_0    Anaconda
tensorflow-base           1.10.0          gpu_py36had579c0_0    Anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            1.10.0               hf154084_0    Anaconda
```

Finally tested tensorflow again

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('hi,tensorflow')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>>
```

It all worked. The issue was that nvidia driver was not compatible with cuda tensorflow so i updated to latest and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helped to revert back to tensorflow 1.9.0 as was suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9549) (Anaconda had installed version 1.10.0). It automatically installs the correct version of Cuda (9.0 instead of 9.2 out of my head). Downgrading is simple in Anaconda:

`conda install tensorflow=1.9.0`

That worked for me. This setup works with Keras 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

In the case I just solved, it was updating the GPU driver to the latest and installing the cuda toolkit. First, the ppa was added and GPU driver installed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

After adding the ppa, it showed options for driver versions, and 390 was the latest 'stable' version that was shown.

Then install the cuda toolkit:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

It updated the drivers to a newer version than the 390 originally installed in the first step (it was 410; this was a p2.xlarge instance on AWS).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0" # To adapt!
```