# Tensorflow: failed to create session in server

Tags: python, tensorflow

I developed a model in Keras and trained it quite a few times. Once I forcefully stopped the training of the model and since then I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inception_resnet.py", line 246, in <module>
    callbacks=[checkpoint, saveEpochNumber])   ##
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2042, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1762, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2270, in __call__
    session = get_session()
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 163, in get_session
    _SESSION = tf.Session(config=config)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1486, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 621, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/eh0/E27890/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

So the error is actually

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to
>   create session.

And most probably, the GPU memory is still occupied. I can't even create a simple tensorflow session.

I have seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775164/5254777), but when I execute the following command in terminal

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
```

training of the model gets started without GPU acceleration.

Also, as I am training my model on a server and I have no root access either to the server, I can't restart the server or clear GPU memory with root access. What is the solution now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in a comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197286/how-can-i-flush-gpu-memory-using-cuda-physical-reset-is-unavailable).

```
nvidia-smi -q
```

This gives a list of all the processes (and their PIDs) occupying GPU memory. I killed them one by one by using

```
kill -9 PID
```

Now everything is running smooth again.

Comment: I got the same error while my GPU usage is all zero, how do you find processes taking gpu memory in the output of `nvidia-smi -q`

Comment: Find the "Processes" in the result, where you will find Process ID @K.Wanter

Comment: thank you, turns out my problem was caused by driver version insufficient for cuda runtime version, update drive solve the problem

Comment: The "Processes" shows blank in my system. Also nvidia-smi shows 0% GPU utilization.  Is there any other way around without restarting the server?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Anaconda 4.5.12 with python 3.5, NVIDIA Driver 390.116
and also faced the same issue.
In my case this was caused by incompatible cudatoolkit version

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

installed cudatoolkit 9.3.0 with cudnn 7.3.x. However after going through answers [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9549) and referring to my other virtual environment where I use pytorch with GPU without any problem I inferred that `cudatookit 9.0.0` will be compatible with my driver version.

```
conda install cudatoolkit==9.0.0
```

**This installed `cudatoolkit 9.0.0` and `cudnn 7.3.0` from `cuda 9.0_0` build. After this I was able to create tensorflow session with GPU.**

Now coming to the options of killing jobs

- If you have GPU memory occupied by other jobs then killing them one by one as suggested by @Preetam saha arko will free up GPU and may allow you to create `tf` session with GPU (provided that compatibility issues are resolved already)
- To create Session with specified GPU, kill the previous `tf.Session()` request after finding PID from `nvidia-smi` and set cuda visible device to available GPU ID (`0` for this example)

  `import os
   os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]='0'`

  Then using `tf.Session` can create session with specified GPU device.
- Otherwise, if nothing with GPU works then kill the previous `tf.Session()` request after finding PID from `nvidia-smi` and set cuda visible device to undefined

  `import os
   os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=''`

  Then using `tf.Session` can create session with CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, while working on the cluster. When I submitted the job script to Slurm server , it would run fine but while training the model on Jupytyter notebook, I would get the following error :

InternalError: Failed to create session

Reason : It was because I was running multiple jupyter notebooks under same GPU (all of them using tensorflow), so slurm server would restrict to create a new tensorflow session.
The problem was solved by stopping all the jupyter notebook, and then running only one/two at a time.

Below is the log error for jupyter notebook :

Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; total memory reported: 12786073600

Comment: @obscure can you please clarify. Is my answering style wrong , or what I have mentioned in the answer is wrong ?